# Date conversion error - MS Access front end querying sql back end

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I am getting a date conversion error when trying to execute SQL from and an Access database against a SQL database.  Our machines are all running windows 7 with office 2010.  The front end is an accde.

There is a search form in the database and all the fields work fine, except the two date fields.

The query's where clause looks like this in the front ends VB code

```
"WHERE DrawnDate BETWEEN #" & Format(FromDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# AND #" & _
    Format(ToDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#"
```

Based on some research, I have also tried date formats of `dd-mon-yyyy` and `dd-mm-yyyy` with no change in outcome.

> The expression On Click you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: ODBC -- call failed.

The error received is:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/ or time from character string. (#241)

The other problem is that this only happens on one PC so far and not on mine or others that I have tested.

Comment: Does that SQL get passed **straight** through to SQL Server? If so, I think it's not going to like the hash character. If this is the case, maybe try changing the hash character to a single quote. Also, can you confirm DrawnDate is a DateTime column?

Comment: No it isn't going straight through as the tables are linked tables in access.  That is why the quotes have to be there (that was my first thought too :)  DrawnDate is of SQL datetime type.  The really odd thing for me is the face it works on most machines but doesn't work on one... and it's the one who uses this date field all the time!

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure then. Sorry mate. I'd maybe suggest checking your ODBC connection from the machine that is failing to a machine that is working though. Check through all the settings (Language and all) and make sure they are all the same.

Comment: Two things come to mind- one is the machine in question could be using 'Regional' currency and Date setting in the ODBC configuration.  The other could be a simple matter of giving Access what it expects between hash marks- "mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: Checked the ODBC settings on a working PC v a non working PC and they are the same.  Will try the date format next.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had this exact same error on just one machine and solved it by removing, then re-adding our reference to DAO360.DLL (Under Visual Basic Tools->References). It never showed as MISSING.

This is definitely not a pass-through (i.e. uses a linked table), as the # date literal termination character is definitely an Access/Jet thing.  ODBC Trace showed a change in the generation of the actual SQL sent to SQL Server after the "re-reference".

Comment: This did it for me +1

Comment: When I deployed an .accde copy to a PC that didn't have one of the components installed, most of the Access forms and reports ran, but not all of them. The error thrown was about converting a date. But the problem was a missing reference. Running the .accdb file displayed a different error message, about the missing reference.

Answer (score 3):

The question is, whether your query is a Pass-Through-Query or not (the fact that the table is linked is irrelevant). If the query is Pass-Through then you must write it in the SQL-Server dialect, otherwise in Access dialect. Pass-Through is a property of the query, not a property of the table.

Another point is whether the date lies within the valid date range of the SQL-Server. These ranges are different for Access and SQL-Server:

> **SQL-Server**
> *datetime*  (January 1, 1753 - December 31, 9999)
> *datetime2* (January 1, 0001 to December 31, 9999)
> *smalldatetime* (January 1, 1900 to June 6, 2079)
> *date* (January 1, 0001 to December 31, 9999)
>
> **Access**
> *Date/Time* (January 1, 100 A.D. -December 31, 9999 A.D.)

A date value of 0 (the default value) represents December 30, 1899 in Access and this lies outside of the `smalldatetime` range of SQL-Server.

The `Format` function does not work if the value passed to it is a `String`. Make sure the `FromDate` and `ToDate` variables are declared `As Date` in VBA or that they are variants containing a date. `VarType(FromDate)` should return `7` (=`vbDate`) in the latter case. If they are variants they should also not be `Null`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Microsoft office bug.

This problem mainly occurs when you have any "reference issue" in macro/VBA.

Follow following steps

1. Go to visual basic Editor or Press (Alt + F11 )
2. Click on menu Tools->References
3. Uncheck any library reference that starts with the word "Missing:..."
4. Now try to execute a query

Answer (score 1):

Kevin Moore's post solved this for me.  Nearly all of the PCs running my DB under Access 2016 had no issue with it, but so far two have thrown the exact error the original poster ran into. As this is years later and two Office versions later, I figured it was worth mentioning this issue still exists.

A simple DLOOKUP to read a date from a table on an SQL Server connected via the SQL Server 2012 Native Client threw the error, and removing and re-adding that specific reference fixed it (with a compile attempt that threw an error due to the missing reference performed between the removal and re-addition).

By the way, in your References window, that DLL is named "Microsoft Office XX.X Access database engine Object Library", with the "XX.X" being your Office version (16.0 for Office 2016 in my case), and the actual NAME of the DLL won't be visible due to Microsoft not having the References form large enough or sizable, and not wrapping text for the Location.  Here it is selected:
[image: DAO360.DLL selected in References window]

Answer (score 0):

I made a change to Access and a stored procedure at the same time, then received this error. I thought it was Access related and spent a long time with posts like this before I tested the stored proc itself. Only to find the proc was returning this exact message. Fixed the proc and of course, everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by simply de-compiling my application then compact and repair.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31005282)

Comment: I feel that it does answer the question. I had the exact same error message described by the asker. I de-compiled my application, then I ran a compact and repair and it fixed the error. How is that not an answer to the question?